# Is this type of while loop acceptable in Java?

Tags: java

I have seen this form used in some snippets and I was wondering if this is a correct implementation of a while loop in Java:

```
while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contentBytes)) != -1) {
    response = new String(contentBytes, 0, bytesRead);
    responseBuffer.append(response);
}
```

Comment: What makes a `while` loop acceptable?

Comment: the usage of a "==" instead of the "="

Comment: and why is this question tagged with android?

Comment: @Nactus try using "=" and compiler will tell you : )

Comment: @Nactus that `=` is an assignment. then you compare the value assinged with `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads a byte from contentByte and stores it in bytesRead, then if the byte read is not the end of file (-1 indicates end of file)  it executes the statements in the loop body. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's perfectly legal. It is quite often used with `read()` methods and streams like in your example.

Comment: thanks Michal, that's what I needed to know. I'll accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow allows it.